# Good Code Spell Checker for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, spell-checking, vsx

Are there any good (preferably free) solutions out there?
I have already found these:

- [Spell Checker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce)
- [Code Spelling Checker Extension for Visual Studio 2010 (VSX)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SpellSharp.aspx)

but will appreciate more suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a Resharper user, try the [Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) plugin.